# How to list map is inside map in React Js. Please gate explanation the mistake in my project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to studding react Js. I try to make one study project in react. Now I feel on problem issue.  How to list map is inside map in React Js.  Please gate explanation the mistake in my project.

https://react-q64zzj.stackblitz.io

```
export default function App() {
  const tabdata = [
    {
      title: "1 img",
      img: "IT-companies-scaled-1270x675.jpg",
    },
    {
      title: "2 img",
      img: "List-of-IT-Companies-in-Panchkula.jpeg",
      list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    },
  ];
  return (
    <>
      {tabdata.map((d, i) => {
        return <Try title={d.title} img={d.img} list={d.list} />;
      })}
    </>
  );
}

export default function Try(props) {
  const Items = props.list;
  console.log("type " + typeof props.list);
  console.log("Data " + props.list);

  const listItems = Items.map((number) => <li>{number}</li>);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.title}</h3>
      <img src={props.img} />
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-q64zzj?file=src/

Comment: Please read [ask]. It *really* helps if you [tell us what the problem is](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a condition to check the list exists

```
<Try
 key={i}
 title={data.title}
 img={data.img}
 list={data?.list ? data.list : []}
  />
```

Answer (score -3):

change `tabdata`
to

```
const tabdata= [
        {
          title: '1 img',     
          img:"IT-companies-scaled-1270x675.jpg",
          list:[],
        },
        {
          title: '2 img',
          img:"List-of-IT-Companies-in-Panchkula.jpeg",
          list:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        },
      ];
```

i think const Items = props.list; get undefield or null in your

```
export default function Try(props)
```

also if you cant change the tabdata you need to check if the list is exist or not